# how to center div in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After googling for hours, I am still stuck at this problem. Since I used `flex-direction:column`, to align the child divs hence, I used `justify-content:center` but the child divs look aligned to the left.

```
<div class=container>
    <div class= "wrapper">
        <div class = "image-float">
            <img class = "profile-picture" src = "{% static 'images/image.jpg'%}">
         </div>
         <div>
             <p>Welcome to Sparison...</p> 
         </div>
         <div class="intro">
             <h1>Copy code below and share with friends</h1>
         </div>
         <div class="url-container input-group">
             <input type="text" id="random" class="url input-border form-control" value="">
             <div class="input-group-append">
                 <span class="input-border input-group-append input-group-text">
                     <i class="far fa-copy url-copy-icon"></i></span>
             </div>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is below:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: var(--very-pale-blue);
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;  
}

.container{
max-width: 100%;
height: 90vh;
margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.url-container .input-group {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 50%;
  /* background-color: #1DB954; */
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

[image]

Above is how the page renders. every element under the wrapper div should be in the middle of the page centered vertically.

Comment: Add `align-items: center;` to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about flex here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

```
  .wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y4qra692/

Answer (score 0):

Change the container width

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then for the wrapper as you have changed the flex-direction to column you now need align-items rather than justify-content as (confusingly) when you change the direction these properties swap around:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It works but I do not understand this. I read that `align-items` is used to position elements on the cross axis, which in my case right now, since `flex-direction:column`, is the horizontal axis. How is my vertical alignment problem solved then since I am trying to align centrally on the vertical axis?

Comment: It switches axes around when you change flex-direction, so swap properties align-items and justify-content when you use flex-direction: column. Try a quick test between row and column you will see

Answer (score 0):

To make div centered you can add this code to .wrapper

```
    .wrapper{
     width: 50%;
     margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To make a div centered:

```
<section class="middle">
    <div class="div">
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Style.css

```
.middle {
    height: 100vh; /* or height you want */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```